# fwrite() without indention / whitespaces

Tags: php, xml, fwrite

I have this simple setup here:

```php
<?php
fwrite($handle, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 <rss version ="2.0"     xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
                 <channel>
                 <title>' . $sTitel . '</title>
                 <description>' . $sDescription . '<description>');
```

As you can see, there are several whitespaces in the 2nd line which is to be written. Obviously, `fwrite` interprets them and writes them to the file as well. This is what I don't wann to have.

My file-output looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <rss version ="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
                    <channel>
                    <title>myTitle</title>
                    <description>myDesct<description>
```

`trim` doesn't remove the whitespaces. I keep this formatting for the readability and indention. Sure, one solution would be to write it like this:

```php
<?php
class myClass {
    public function writeStuff() {
        fwrite($handle, "here
comes
my
content");
    }
}
```

But you see, this isn't very readable. Any ideas? Also, I want to keep tabs (or whitespaces) for a usual xml-structure (guess I could work with `\t` for that?

My expected result should be this (xml-file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version ="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
     <title></title>
     <description><description>
     <link>http://dfu.dev12-1.tro.net/oxid49/<link>
     <item>
         <g:id>531a8af7d9a9a5bb53b65a2b9a5356e5</g:id>
     </item>
</channel>
```

Comment: *"trim doesn't remove the whitespaces"* - I don't see where you're using [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Tried it in my code before asking the question, that is why I removed it again. Otherwise I couldn't have made that statement

Comment: Trim removes leading and trailing whitespaces, not contained whitespaces so it makes sense that it doesn't work here.

Comment: @apokryfos agreed. But it was worth a try nevertheless. :)

Comment: I would advise using Dom Document of PHP it can help you writing XML and has lots of options. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and for your whitespace, you may want to see http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate each line. You've defined a literal string with lots of spaces (or tabs) in it. Added spaces where necessary.

```
fwrite($handle, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL
       .'<rss version ="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">'.PHP_EOL
       .'<channel>'.PHP_EOL
       .'    <title>' . $sTitel . '</title>'.PHP_EOL
       .'    <description>' . $sDescription . '<description>'.PHP_EOL);
```

A bit more readable and you still keep control of the output.

Comment: It's probably better to write spaces as spaces instead of using tabs. PHP has a nice function called `str_repeat` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php

Comment: Neat idea, but this way it puts all the text next to each other. Working with `\n` doesn't work for the 1. line :/

Comment: I've added newlines, they "should" work, don't know why they wouldn't.

Comment: Figured it out. Working with `\r\n` requires `" "` instead of `' '` :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @DasSaffe I tend to use PHP_EOL because it deals with environment specific newlines so you can have a more portable code.